# Serializing int type without quotes

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class to be serializing:

```
[Serializable]
public class LabelRectangle { 
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int X { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int Y { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int Width { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

and it is going to be serialized and looks like this

```
<LabelRectangle X="15" Y="70" Width="10" Height="1" />
```

but I would like to get the following result:

```
<LabelRectangle X=15 Y=70 Width=10 Height=1 />
```

that is serializing int type values without quotes. Is it possible and how if yes?

Comment: I don't think that what you want to achieve is valid XM, so you will have to write your own serializer based on XML.

Comment: Why would you want that? It's not valid XML anymore then, which means it can't be read by other programs without additional effort on their side.

Comment: btw; `XmlSerializer` doesn't care about `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this would **not** be a well formed XML anymore - you defined the Attribute

```
[XmlAttribute]
```

Attribute values are always in quotes!!

Answer (score 3):

You should not do that. Attribute values must always be quoted. Either single or double quotes can be used. So this is correct:

```
 <LabelRectangle X="15" Y="70" Width="10" Height="1" />
```

This is not:

```
 <LabelRectangle X=15 Y=70 Width=10 Height=1 />
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).

Why do you want to deviate from the rules? Never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

XML attributes do not know types and their values are always enquoted. So this is on purpose.

See also the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue):

```
AttValue  ::=  '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
               |  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

So all attribute values are either enquoted with double quotes `"` or with single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make it an element as attributes are always in quotes.

```
[XmlElement(DataType = "int",
ElementName = "Height")]
public int Height { get; set; }
```