# XmlAttributeAttribute type in generated XML file

Tags: c#

When I serialize this class:

```
public class Camera
{
    ------ // other informations
    private long cameraIdField;
    ------

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public long CameraId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cameraIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cameraIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file produced contains the value of cameraID between "" :

```
<CameraId>"0"<CameraId>
```

What I need is the int value like this :

```
<CameraId>0<CameraId>
```

How can I export the cameraId as an int ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? Note that using an automatically implemented property would cut that class size down to 5 lines, including braces...

Comment: Declaring the property as `[XmlAttribute]` should make the serializer convert it to an actual attribute `<Camera CameraId="0" />` in that case. So the output should be different than what you describe here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing int type without quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343250/serializing-int-type-without-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

Class:

```
public class Camera
{
    [XmlElement]
    public long CameraId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Xml { get { return Extension.ToXmlString<Camera>(this); } }
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Camera xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CameraId>2</CameraId>
</Camera>
```

You had to use XML element instead of attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is working, The cameraId was exported as an attribute. Thanks WagoL !